# Add element jquery to html

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, xampp

Anyway to add new question when I click add question. Add using append or other way?
[Interface image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRX1B.png)

```js
$(".question_option #add_question").click(function() {
  console.log("Add question");
  //Add question using 
  $(".question_info").append("Do something add here.");
});
```

```html
<div class="question_info">
  <div id="1">
    <!--Question 1-->
    <p>Question ??</p>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter question"></textarea>
    <p class="words">???/???</p>
    <input class="add_correct" type="button" value="Add correct answer">
    <input class="add_wrong" type="button" value="Add wrong answer">
    <!-- Add answer -->


    <input class="delete_question" type="button" value="Delete question">
    <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Enter answer">-->
  </div>

  <!--
            Add more question
            -->
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I trying to use append but if you enter at $("??").append("example **ENTER** hi"); this won't work.
[Error image when enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWi21.png)
Or I should do it without enter but that will be a mess.
I want to copy the html question 1 code to query to add new question when click button.

Anyway to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: Could try the backtick

Comment: If you want to use "multiple lines" in your append to make it looks better when you code you can use these ` (tilted single quote) Look here https://jsfiddle.net/5qhcrLjo/

Comment: I try again will backtick(search using google what is that) it works! Thx. I dont even know backtick exist. So much i need to learn.

Comment: The alternative is to use `" +\n "` to break up your lines:  `"line 1" + [newline] " line 2"`.  Similar fiddle to above: https://jsfiddle.net/1fnude8w/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using jquery as you already calling onlick function so in your onclick function use:

```
var time = Date.now();

$('.question_info').append('<div id="'+time+'"><p>Question ??</p><textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Enter question"></textarea><p class="words">???/???</p><input class="add_correct" type="button" value="Add correct answer"><input class="add_wrong" type="button" value="Add wrong answer"><input class="delete_question" type="button" value="Delete question"><input type="text" placeholder="Enter answer"></div>');
```